# Add a class if the clicked element does not contain <a> children

Tags: jquery

At the moment,when clicking a box, this box is added a class with this code:

```
$("#box").click(function(ev) {  
   $(this).addClass("new");
});
```

Now I want an addition so that the class is *only added if* that box does not contain a `<a>` link on the first level (it's children may contain links, but no children may be links). Something along the lines of this:

```
$("#box").click(function(ev) {  
   $(this).(":not(:has(a))").addClass("new");
});
```

I hope you understand my intention. Any good methods for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like below:-

```
$("#box").click(function(ev) {  
   if(!$(this).children('a').length){
     $(this).addClass("new");
   }
});
```

Comment: @Steeven   glad to help you :):)